# How to import files from RepoA to RepoB whilst maintaining the commits associated to these files?

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository, commit

Inside `RepoA`, there's a directory(`directoryA`) with some files(`file1`, `file2`, `file3`) and I want to move these files from `RepoA` to `RepoB`.

This is `RepoA`:

```
RepoA
    directoryA
        file1
        file2
        file3
    directoryB
        file1
        file2
        file3
```

After what I want to do, `RepoB` would look like:

```
RepoB
    directoryA
        file1
        file2
        file3
```

I could just download `directoryA` from `RepoA` and upload it to `RepoB`, but I would lose the commits associated with `file1`, `file2` and `file3`.

I also can't transfer the whole `RepoA` to `RepoB` (as in a merge), because the commits from `directoryB` would be irrelevant in `RepoA`.

**Edit**: I tried using the `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter directoryName -- --all`

It doesn't work for me, everytime I try to pull after executing that command I get the error:

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Comment: Yo mean you wish to keep the history from repo A? all of it or just for the files related to the directory?

Comment: I only want the history of the files I'm moving, not the whole Repo A history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please make a new branch and check it out for this process, since the following operation will modify the history of local RepoA and delete some files:

**In local RepoA**,

```
(1) git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter directoryA <branch>
(2) mkdir directoryA
(3) mv * directoryA
(4) git add .
(5) git commit -am 'message'
```

**In local RepoB**,

```
(6) git remote add repoA <local RepoA’s path>
(7) git pull RepoA <branch>
```

If you get the error: `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories` during step `(7)`, you can pull ignoring the unrelated histories by doing `git pull RepoA <branch> --allow-unrelated-histories`

Then `file1`, `file2` and `file3`'s commit histories will show in RepoB. You can use `gitk --all` to view more clearly.

For more detail, please refer [here](http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/). (The top two comments ([this](http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/#comment-700639747) and [this](http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/#comment-620022290)) might clarify it further).

Comment: Doesn't work. The other directories that were in repo-a disappeared.
Also, I can't pull from local repo-a to repo-b: I get the error >> fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Comment: I just finished reading the reference you mentioned and also read the comments. All of them always result in the same error and it happens always in the same step (pull step) $ fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Comment: Yes, after the first command, you will find RepoA only have files which were included in the subfolder are now in the root directory of the RepoA. That’s why the second and third command do: put the files in the subfolder again. For the git pull step, you can try `git pull RepoA master --allow-unrelated-histories` instead.

Comment: What are the possible implications of this? Do you know if I should be concerned about something that might happen in the future in this repository? Any history conflict or something.

Comment: This is caused your RepoA and RepoB has no related commit, files or histroy. It doesn’t matter for you to get the information `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories` when you really want to pull or merge, just add `--allow-unrelated-histories`.

Comment: The flag `--allow-unrelated-histories` made it work. Thank you very much.